What triggers Vue 2 to error in initBackend?
Over the last day or so Vue 2.7.14 has been reporting an error in the Chrome console:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Vue')
at initBackend (backend.js:2088:28)

It does this about 50% of the time during my single page app page load. It doesn't seem to impact the loading or functioning of my page, and it wasn't there last week. I can't figure out why this is now happening.
If it's relevant, Vue DevTools seems flakier than usual. I need to close and reopen Chrome DevTools a few times a day.


The error is specific to backend.js which we know nothing about. Please include the relevant code.

This basically means that there's a problem with vue devtools. It's unknown what the version. Since you cannot normally affect the way it works, you generally need to keep it up to date, otherwise downgrade

@yoduh It belongs to vue devtools
